# EXCEL: Keeping only the unique values with the highest value in another column

Tags: excel, parsing, function, sorting

In my two columns of data I would like to keep only the unique values of ColumnOne that have the highest value in ColumnTwo.

For example

```
ColumnOne       ColumnTwo
2                  6
3                  2
7                  8
2                  7
3                  4
7                  3
```

So in this example my output would be:

```
      2                  7
      7                  8
      3                  4
```

because this is the unique values in ColumnOne with the highest values in ColumnTwo.

I tried using the formula

```
    "=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,[ IF(B2>____  )1,0 ], 0)"
```

but I am stuck on what to put in this portion

```
   "IF(B2>____)."
```

This is what I am trying to say in the function:
**If** the value in the first column is repeated more than once

1. **Than** if the corresponding B column has a greater value PRINT 1 ELSE PRINT 2
2. **Else**Print 0

Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You say you need the unique values of ColumnOne, but in the results, you list 7 twice, and you also list 2, which isn't unique.

Comment: Chloe-I apologize I was having computer trouble. I read over my question several times and I did not realize it was not edited correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the original data you could put this formula in C2

`=(B2=MAX(IF(A$2:A$7=A2,B$2:B$7)))*(SUM(IF(A$2:A2=A2,IF(B$2:B2=B2,1)))=1)`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copied down

That will place a 1 against the first instance of each row containing the MAX B value for each distinct A value, zero otherwise.

You can filter by 1s in column C to see just those rows

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have already built a first column without duplicates:

```
Col A   Col B
2        7
7        8
3        4
```

Here is the formula you can put in col B to get the expected results:

```
{=MAX((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=A2)*Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)}
```

This is an array formula you have to validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding and your help! I apologize for my editing errors.